# File as command line argument of Docker python app

Tags: python, docker

I need to create dockerized python application that will read file from command line.

I don't know if it's possible, but my specification for running this app is:

```
docker run -t myimage file.csv
```

At the moment my docker file look like this:

```
FROM python:3
ADD test.py /
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "test.py"]
CMD ["test.py"]
```

Where test.py is:
import sys

```
def main(args):
    for a in args:
        print(a)
        with open(a, 'r') as f:
            for l in f:
                print(l)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docker container won't see the file unless you map it into the container as a volume. That syntax would look like:

```
docker run -t -v `pwd`/file.csv:/file.csv myimage file.csv
```

That maps ./file.csv into the container as /file.csv, and then your script in the container will run:

```
python test.py file.csv
```

You can also use the docker cli to pipe input into the container, replacing stdin. From the CLI, you need to include `-i` to make it interactive, and then use the normal shell redirection like:

```
docker run -it myimage <file.csv
```

If you do this, you'd need to update your python script to read from stdin instead of the file, and you wouldn't have the option to be interactive with the python script if you were using stdin for other things.

Comment: So my specification is wrong and can't be meet in any way?

Comment: It can be met in two ways, listed above. But as written, it won't work because you have not placed file.csv inside the container.